# How to change the status from 'Pending Payment' to 'Processing' using REST API in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

We are using REST API interface of Magento 2.3.4 to process orders. Followed 7 steps given in the following link and also added code to capture the payment.

[Creating Order in Magento 2](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/tutorials/orders/order-create-order.html)

As soon as the payment is captured the status doesn't change from **Pending Payment** to **Processing**. However, if we click on **Get Payment Update** option from Admin panel for the order, status changes to **Processing**. Any idea which REST API needs to be called to change the status to 'Processing'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the status we used V1/orders/{orderId}/comments end point. Fill in the following fields(Sample value is given in the request body).

```
{
   "statusHistory" : {
        "comment": "Payment Successful",
        "is_customer_notified": 1,
        "is_visible_on_front": 0,
        "parent_id": 121123,  <-- This is orderId
        "status": "processing"
    }
}
```

[API Reference](https://devdocs.magento.com/redoc/2.3/admin-rest-api.html#operation/salesOrderManagementV1AddCommentPost)